# Could a public IP with blocked public inbound/outbound traffic be a risk?

Tags: network, firewalls, ip, threats

If we have a device that for some reason needs a public IP address and if at the same time the device should only be accessible from within a private network: Could the fact that the public IP of the device exists pose a security threat? I'm referring to scenarios:

a) where all inbound traffic to the device from outside the private network would be blocked via an NSG or a firewall but public outbound traffic is allowed.

b) both public inbound and public outbound traffic are blocked.

I'm also assuming that all traffic from inside the private network is not a risk.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Please specifiy the Cloud provider if you're using the cloud.